# How do I write on next row when exceed row's height size?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a layout of form like a math test paper.
like this...
[math test paper image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r42m.png)

I will use flutter_math package for math expressions.

If I made this form with html/css, I would use a column style in css code.
In flutter, I can't implement to move next row when exceed row's height size.
I have no idea..
I think It needs detailed painting process in build method.Is it right?
Give me any ideas or directions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in Flutter if we want an input field to accept auto multiline input
set  `keyboardType` to `TextInputType.multiline` and `maxLines` to `null`

```
TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      maxLines: null,
    )
```

If the `maxLines` property is `null`, there is no limit to the number of lines, and the wrap is enabled.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying to my novice question. What I want is the movement of text in a 2-column structure. When text overflows in one column, isn't there a way to write the text to the next column instead of moving it within the text field?    (Column or Row)